# Large .txt file (15.5mb) parsed using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fopen, fgets

My task is to parse a large .txt file (circa. 15,000 lines) into a MySQL database. The problem is I'm working with a 30 second maximum execution time. I've tried using this:

```
        $handle = @fopen('http://www.someothersiteyouknow.com/bigfile.txt', "r"); 
    if ($handle) { 
       while (!feof($handle)) { 
           $lines[] = fgets($handle, 4096); 
       } 
       fclose($handle); 
    }
```

I can then access the $lines array and parse the data whichever way I need to but it takes too long for the script to finish running. My feeling is that I should read the file in chunks, maybe 1000 lines at a time. But I only understand how to read from the beginning of the .txt file. Please may you impart some ideas for methods of doing this correctly? Just to clarify, I don't require specific code examples, just ideas for how to parse large .txt files using PHP.

Comment: Have you tried [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)?

Comment: Are you manipulating the data in any way before inserting it?

Comment: I haven't tried fread, it looks useful. Thanks.
I am manipulating the data, using explode() and such.

Comment: what kind of content is in the txt file, sql querys or CSV's? as splitting the content using an initial function of such shouldn't be that hard, then once each small file is completed its removed.

Comment: It is plain text delimited by a newline. Each line corresponds to a product. Saving a local copy then removing the data by the chunk as its processed seems like a good idea. Many thanks.

Comment: why dont you just change the max execution time with [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or import the file directly with [MySql's LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: I'm afraid changing the max execution time is not an option as I'm on shared hosting and safe mode is on. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem like the best idea, to be honest.  What if multiple users access the same page at, or around, the same time?  You'll have (number of users*large text file) being processed concurrently.

Suggest you bring the file local (save it locally if the file doesn't already exist), and work with the local file.  This should help reduce your transaction time

This should help bring you into the 30s limit ... if the file doesn't take longer than 30s to download!

Comment: I will follow your advice and save a local copy of the file. I think I'm ready to re-approach this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting a [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) inside your loop.

Also if this is a once-off thing you could look at doing it with mySQL's [load data file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

If you can put your file on the server, then you may try to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` query. It has plenty of options to parse the input, and works reasonably fast. Start experimenting with the small portion of your file. If the server ends up inserting everything into the single row, then tune the `LINES TERMINATED BY` part, by specifying  `'\n'` or `'\r\n'`. Then double check the number of rows against the number of lines in the file, and `SELECT` some of them to see what ended up in the table.